# Why doesn't my dialog drag or resize?

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, resize, drag

I am unable to drag or resize a dialog box. I have downloaded all dependencies and tried various settings in options, but still no joy:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dialog(){
$("#paragraph").dialog({
    title: 'This is a title',
    width: 300,
    height: 50,
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
            'Remove': function () { // remove what you want to remove 
                // do something here 
                alert("this is a test alert!");
                $(this).dialog('close');
                $("#flex1").flexReload();
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
});
$("#paragraph").dialog("open");
};
</script>

<p id="paragraph">This is some paragraph text</p>
```

Comment: why do i have to have ui.draggable.js included in my head statement? i didn't think you needed that or resizeable. should it not be included in the ui.custom file? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Downloads of the jQuery UI library are customizable.  If your copy doesn't include the 'Draggable' and 'Resizable' interactions, your dialog will not be draggable or resizable.

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe add resizable option and set it to true.

Also the dialog is draggable by the title bar not the entire dialog body.

Any good?

Comment: i already have draggable: true in my code. also have tried same with resizeable. thanks

Comment: I meant you can only drag the box by click/holding on the title bar